# How can I search a collection to find a nested value in one of its documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, robo3t

[image: Screenshot of database in Robomongo]

In the screenshot above you can see that I have open a document named **(1) ObjectId(572b...ec7a)** from my **tests** collection in my mongo database. (the **tests** collection is full of documents like this) Near the bottom of the screenshot you can see there is a field named **Name** that is type string with a value of **EditMessagesSettings**. I would like to query the **tests** collection and return any document that contains a particular **Name** (such as **EditMessagesSettings** in this case). How can I do this?

Here are some of the queries I have attempted without success, getting an return message like *Fetched 0 record(s) in 4ms*.

- db.getCollection('tests').find({Name:"EditMessagesSettings"})
- db.getCollection('tests').find({Name:{$regex:"Settings"}})

Edit: if it is any constellation, if I type in *db.getCollection('tests').find({Obj})*, I get an auto-complete option of *ObjectId(*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see where the problem is. You need to use two underscores instead of one. See the example below:

_value vs. the correct one __value.

So your query should look like:

```
db.getCollection('tests').find({"Data.__value.Name":"EditMessagesSettings"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
db.getCollection('tests').find({"Data._value.Name":"EditMessagesSettings"})
```

Comment: The result of this query: Fetched 0 record(s) in 5ms.